# How to assign variables with multiple returns in PHP?

Tags: php

I know in python we can do

```
Def foo():
   return "foo", "bar", 10

a, b, c = foo()
```

In php I have to do

```
public function bar(){
   return ["foo", "bar"]
}

$arr = bar()
$a = $arr[0]
$b = $arr[1]
```

Is there anyway I can assign multiple variables from function returns in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return multiple values with Python but you can't with PHP, however, you can return multiple value in form of an array and use [list()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to assign value to variables as if they were in an array

```
function bar(){
   return ["foo", "bar"];
}

list($a, $b) = bar();
echo $a; // show "foo"
echo $b; // show "bar"
```